# Convert nested Oracle-style query (with subqueries) to ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I've got the following Oracle-style query that I have to convert to an ANSI SQL query so that I can understand what kind of joins they are:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    (SELECT TABLE1.COL1
        FROM VIEW1 TABLE1
        WHERE TABLE1.COL2 = (
            SELECT TABLE2.COL2
            FROM VIEW2 TABLE2
            WHERE TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID
        )
         AND TABLE1.COL3 = (
            SELECT TABLE2.COL3
            FROM VIEW2 TABLE2
            WHERE TABLE2.COL3 = TABLE3.COL3
        )
FROM VIEW3 TABLE3
```

It's the subqueries that I can't figure out. I have tried going through the Oracle documentation on this subject (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2066611) and tried using Google to search for an example or explanation or what kind of join this is however I can only find information on simpler joins online. I'm really stuck on this one and would appreciate any help.

I have also tried converting this query in Oracle SQL Developer but it doesn't convert the subqueries for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a correlated sub-query; it is not a join and it is ANSI standard:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       ( SELECT v1.COL1
         FROM   VIEW1 v1
         WHERE  v1.COL2 = (SELECT COL2
                           FROM   VIEW2 v2
                           WHERE  v2.ID = v3.ID)
         AND    v1.COL3 = (SELECT v2.COL3
                           FROM   VIEW2 v2
                           WHERE  v2.COL3 = v3.COL3)
       )
FROM   VIEW3 v3
```

---

If you want to convert it to a `JOIN` then:

```sql
SELECT v3.id,
       v1.col1
FROM   view3 v3
       LEFT OUTER JOIN view1 v1
       ON (    EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM   view2 v2a
                 WHERE  v2a.col3 = v3.col3
                 AND    v2a.col3 = v1.col3
               )
           AND EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM   view2 v2b
                 WHERE  v2b.id = v3.id
                 AND    v2b.col2 = v1.col2
               )
           )
```

*Note: this is not identical if `VIEW1` can have multiple rows that will match as your query will return a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception and the query with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return multiple rows; however for all data sets that do not result in an exception they should be identical.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51859dad83ddb953a600e14b135648c8)*